# How do I stop VScode from remembering the saved state of closed files?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Specifically, I don't want vscode to remember my cursor position or code folding in files that I've closed out of. I've looked all throughout the settings and can't seem to find it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The functionality you are looking for was added in v.1.28.0.  See [release notes: do not restore state](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_28#_do-not-restore-view-state-when-reopening-a-file).

> VS Code has always remembered the view state (cursor location, folded
>   sections, etc.) of a file even after the file was closed. There is now
>   a new setting `workbench.editor.restoreViewState` to drop this view
>   state when a file is closed. This allows you to always start at the
>   top of the file after reopening it.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks, bud.